# HTML Dropdown Menu / Typeaheads (From Python to JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask, typeahead

My plan is to create a website where people can write diaries and read others' diaries and I am currently in the middle of implementing a search box where the user may search usernames to read others' diaries (like how you may look up a friend on Facebook), so I wrote the following code for the search box, with the Python code (contains SQLite statements) extracting search results from the database and with the JavaScript constantly performing the search action behind the scene, to output to `search.html` as a dynamic dropdown menu. However, the drop-down part is not working.

Application.py

```
@app.route("/search", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def search():
"""Search published diaries from others."""

    # if user reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        # ensure friends' usernames were submitted
        if not request.form.get("search"):
            return dumbo("No username entered")

        # search user's friends from database
        # append % to q so that user doesn't have to input city/state/postal code in the URL completely/accurately
        # https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm
        friend = request.form.get("search") + "%"
        searches = db.execute("SELECT username FROM writers WHERE username LIKE :friend", friend=friend)

        # output a JSON array of objects, each represents a row from TABLE writers that matches what the user looks for
        return jsonify(searches)

    # else if user reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("search.html")
```

scripts.js

```
$("#friend").keydown(function() {

    // configure typeahead
    $("#friend").typeahead({
        // If true, when suggestions are rendered, pattern matches for the current query in text nodes
        // will be wrapped in a strong element with its class set to {{classNames.highlight}}. Defaults to false.
        highlight: false,
        // The minimum character length needed before suggestions start getting rendered. Defaults to 1.
        minLength: 1
    },
    {
        display: function(suggestion) { return null; },
        limit: 5,
        source: search,
        templates: {
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile(
                "<div>" +
                "<div>{{username}}</div>" +
                "</div>"
            )
        }
    });
    // action after friend is selected from drop-down
    $("#friend").on("typeahead:selected", function(eventObject, suggestion, name) {

        // visit friend's diaries (to be continued)

    });
});

/**
 * Searches database for typeahead's suggestions.
 */
// search calls asyncResults after searching is done (asynchronously)
function search(query, syncResults, asyncResults)
{
    // get usernames matching query (asynchronously)
    var parameters = {
    friend: $("#friend").val()
    };
    $.getJSON(Flask.url_for("search"), parameters)
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        // call typeahead's callback with search results (i.e., friends)
        asyncResults(data);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        // log error to browser's console
        console.log(errorThrown.toString());

        // call typeahead's callback with no results
        asyncResults([]);
    });
}
```

search.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Search
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="{{ url_for('search') }}" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="typeahead" id="friend" name="search" placeholder="Search friends" type="text"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>
            <!-- https://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-link-an-external-javascript-file/ -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="static/scripts.js"></script>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I literally just started learning CS, so please advise as if I am an idiot, thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Application.py`, `POST` method returns `jsonify(searches)` ,

so I think should use `$.post` instead of `$.getJSON` in

```
$.getJSON(Flask.url_for("search"), parameters) 
...
```

Update:

If you get friend from "search" in server,

```
friend = request.form.get("search") + "%"
```

then should change `friend` to `search` in `parameters` in search function

```
var parameters = {
//friend: $("#friend").val()
    search: $("#friend").val()
};
```

Comment: I changed it to `$.post` but the dropdown menu is still not "dropping down" options... Any more advice? @leaf

Comment: use `print` to log `request.form` in server side.It seems that when typeahead calls  `search` , it has no proper form field from `parameters`

Comment: I changed `return jsonify(searches)` to `print (searches)`, but failed to resolve the issue. Please advise, thanks! @leaf

Comment: Answer updated. Log what `request.form` is to help solve thie issue. @AlexChan

Comment: I did what you instructed, @leaf, but still isn't working. Actually I opened up the console and was able to identify the error as "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function." It seems I have to include the typeahead.js plugin as my source. I looked at some websites, e.g. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27478953/typeerror-typeahead-is-not-a-function) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011594/typeerror-typeahead-is-not-a-function-even-including-typehead-js) but wasn't able to link my code to the right library. I have the latest CS50 IDE (v109). Any idea?

Comment: In your html file, add `jQuery` then `typeahead.js` script tag. Why unable to link code to the right library?

Comment: Hi @leaf, I added `jQuery` in my layout.html, which is extended to search.html. I think I am using jQuery 3.1.1 (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js) and bootstrap 3.3.7 (https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js). How should I add `typeahead.js`? (Thanks again for helping out!)

Comment: Hi, if you use [twitter/typeahead.js/](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/), then you can try download and add `typeahead.js/dist/typeahead.bundle.js`.

Comment: I had followed all the instructions, but it still did not work out. I will be moving on for now to finish the remainder of the project and perhaps coming back to this before wrapping this up. I appreciate all the helps whatsoever!!!!! @leaf

Comment: Should there be any comment on this, please post it here: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/26293/cs50-final-project-dropdown-menu-typeaheads . I am closing this post to focus everything in one post!